Impact of Closing Client App or Switching User Account on Callable Cloud Function Execution
I use a firebase callable cloud function to delete user data. When an user confirmed deletion in the client app, a callable cloud function would be triggered. The callable cloud function does not return any value and it would take sometime to perform all deletion. On the another hand, the completion block in the client app is empty. I want to know if the client app is closed or login by other user account, will these affect the cloud function running in the backend?
The code in client app looks like this
functions.httpsCallable("deleteUserData").call(callData) { _, _ in
    // do nothing in the completion block
    // the client app may close or login by other user account
}

The callable cloud function looks like this
exports.deleteUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // delete user data here
    // after finished, no value to return
    return null;
}


If you are expecting the callable function to execute indefinitely after being invoked by the client, that will never happen, for two reasons:

Functions have a timeout and will always be shut down after the timeout expires.  It's not possible to let a function run forever.
Functions that return immediately without waiting for any background work to terminate will not complete the way you expect.  They will be shut down as soon as the function returns.

If either of these things happen, you should see some sort of error in the function logs.
It doesn't matter at all what the client does. These behaviors are the same for all functions, and are put into place to help you avoid unexpected bills due to excessive use of backend resources.
If you need unlimited timeout background processing, then Cloud Functions is not the right product for your use case.

I am not expecting the function to execute indefinitely. Instead, I am concerned that the callable function may abruptly terminate during execution if the caller in the client app is cleared. Do we need to maintain a reference to the caller in the client app?

As I said in my answer: "It doesn't matter at all what the client does". The function is going to run to completion, in whatever way it ends up completing, either success or error.  If a client disconnects, it just won't receive the result.
